# Having trouble figuring out what I need to change in order for this code to compile

Tags: prolog

When I try to run this code I get 1 error

```
main.pg:1: user directive caused exception:error(existence_error(procedure,main/0),load/1)
```

I dont know what this is trying to tell me. 1st day using Prolog so I am not sufficient in it yet. I edited it once I made some improvements to get rid of my original 3 errors.
This is my code.

```
:- initialization(main).
type(rabbit,animal).
type(dog,animal).
type(snake,animal).
type(fish,animal).
type(whale,animal).
type(dinosaur,animal).
type(carrot,plant).
type(orange,plant).
type(seaweed,plant).
type(coral,plant).
type(computer,object).
type(car,object).
type(boat,object).
type(submarine,object).

alive(rabbit).
alive(dog).
alive(snake).
alive(fish).
alive(whale).
alive(carrot).
alive(orange).
alive(seaweed).
alive(coral).

mammal(rabbit).
mammal(dog).
mammal(whale).

water(fish).
water(whale).
water(seaweed).
water(coral).
water(boat).
water(submarine).

guess(Thing):- ask_type(Type);
        ((Type==animal;Type==plant)->ask_alive(Life)),
        report(Thing,Type,Life).
ask_type(Type) :- writef("Is it an animal, plant, or object? \n"), read(Type).
ask_alive(Life) :- writef("Is it alive or dead? \n"), read(Life).

report(Thing,Type,Life):-
            type(Thing,Type),
            ((Life==alive)-> alive(Thing); not(alive(Thing))).
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 41, you have a space between a predicate and its arguments, which is not allowed:

> `ask_type(Type) :- writef("Is it an animal, plant, or object? \n"), read (Type).`

Change it to this:

```
ask_type(Type) :- writef("Is it an animal, plant, or object? \n"), read(Type).
```

Now you must follow the rest of the advice from Prolog. Please do not ignore the warnings about singleton variables, they invariably mean that you have misunderstood something important.

1. You have no `main` predicate here. Remove line 1.
2. You have a period in line 44 where you mean to have a comma:

   ```
   report(Thing,Type,Life):-
               type(Thing,Type),
               ((Life==alive)-> alive(Thing); not(alive(Thing))).
   ```
3. The singleton in branch on `Type` on line 37 most certainly means that you did not mean to use a semicolon on that line and instead you probably meant a comma:

   ```
   guess(Thing):- ask_type(Type),
           ((Type==animal;Type==plant)->ask_alive(Life)),
           report(Thing,Type,Life).
   ```

After making these changes, the code will compile, but I make no guarantee it will be right. The lessons here are simple:

- Prolog does not allow whitespace between predicate names and their arguments
- Be careful about `.`, `,` and `;`, they are each essential and if you confuse them, you will have big problems.